# Populating a vector templated types

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions

I am trying to develop Views in an enity component system.

I have a function in the entity manager called View, which returns all components of Type T.
Which works for single template like this.

```
ECSViewTest<T> View()
        {
            //--check if valid code removed

            ComponentArray<T>* componentArray = (ComponentArray<T>*)m_ComponentArrays.at(typeHash);

            ECSViewTest<T> view;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < componentArray->m_Size; i++)
            {
                view.sets.push_back(&componentArray->m_ComponentArray[i]);

            }

            return view;
        }
```

ECSViewTest is simply a wrapper to a Vector of tuples of T, which will be expanded upon later.

```
template<class... Types>
    class ECSViewTest
    {
    public:

        //----------

        std::vector< std::tuple<Types*...>> sets;

        //ITERATOR IMPLEMENTATION
        //EXTRACT TUPLE DATA

    };
```

My question is if it's possible to implement this for multiple types, i.e view could find and return all components for 2 or more given types in the template.

```
template<typename ...Types>
        ECSViewTest<Types...> View()
        {

            //works
            ECSViewTest<Types...> view;

            //cant figure out how the go over the types
            foreach(template Type arg in Types...){

                Get All Entities who have this component type
            }

        //usage
        ECSViewTest<TransformComponent, MeshComponent> view = entityManager.View<TransformComponent, MeshComponent>();
```

How can I "loop" over each Type in types to pull the data for each component?

Comment: It seems like you are looking for [boost::hana::for_each](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Foldable.html#ga2af382f7e644ce3707710bbad313e9c2)

Comment: The general approach here is to use helper templates. One variadic template that is basically a tuple of pointers to vectors and which implements a method that returns a tuple of pointers to the corresponding value of each vector. With that in place, `View()` will require just minimal changes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your suggestion I'll give that a go. Would it be possible for some psuedo code, not sure I follow fully.

Comment: That's, pretty much, is the pseudo code. `std::tuple<std:vector<Types> *...>`. Construct it. Implement an `operator*`. Mission accomplished.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I can't understand how that'll allow for iterating over the Types though, sorry thanks again!

Comment: `...` is what iterates over types. That's exactly what it's for. In some complicated situations, one would need to use a variadic template and specialization to manually work through one type at a time. Every good C++ textbook that covers C++11 should have some examples of that. The reason why it's unlikely that anyone will give you a plug-and-play, copy/pastable answer, is because the shown code is not a [mre].